# Is it possible to ingest live captions from Microsoft Teams into a Bot?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams, teams-toolkit

I am trying to develop a Bot that can ingest live captions from a Teams meeting and parse for certain words / phrases in real time.  I.e. if a user in the meeting says "hello" then the bot should respond "hello, how are you" in the chat.

My main roadblock right now is trying to figure out if the live captions from Teams are accessible from a bot built with the Teams Toolkit for Visual Studio. Does anyone know if this is possible?  And if so, could you point me in the right direction to the docs?

Comment: The functionality you are trying to implement doesn't seem to be feasible

Comment: What about the Transcripts?  Captions might not be accessible in real time, but do you know if transcripts are or not?

Comment: Please refer this [blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/calls-and-meetings/real-time-media-concepts) which explains how to get either a recording or text transcript of a Microsoft Teams meeting. Als refer: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/microsoft365dev/record-calls-and-meetings-the-updaterecordingstatus-api-in-microsoft-graph-is-now-generally-available/

Comment: Please refer this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/apps-in-teams-meetings/api-references?tabs=json#send-real-time-captions-api